# Does the Lorentz invariance of equation of motion guarantee the Lorentz invariance of the solutions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, klein-gordon-equation, lorentz-symmetry

If I have a Lorentz invariant equation of motion, like [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation), is the solution automatically guaranteed to be Lorentz invariant?

I ask this question because of the discussion from [Mark Srednicki's Quantum Field Theory](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) section 3 from equations (3.11) to (3.14). If I have a K-G equation, 
$$ \tag 1 \partial^\mu\partial_\mu\phi -m^2\phi=0,$$
we have a solution of the form
$$ \tag 2\exp (i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} \pm i\omega t),$$
which I do not think is Lorentz invariant for solution with
$i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} + i\omega t$
as an argument, unless we allow $k^\mu = (-\omega, \mathbf{k})$.

However, he starts constructing a Lorentz invariant solution, and comes up with 
$$ \tag 3 \phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \int d\tilde{k}[ a(\mathbf{k})e^{ikx} + a^*(\mathbf{k})e^{-ikx}],$$
where
$kx = \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t$.
$d\tilde{k}$ is a Lorentz invariant measure and argument of each exponents are Lorentz invariant as well.

However, he says in the beginning that $a(\mathbf{k})$ is an arbitrary function of the wave vector $\mathbf{k}$, which does not sound Lorentz invariant to me. So I am not sure how $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$ is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: no. When it does not happen we talk of [spontaneous symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking). Have also a look at [this answer of Qmechanic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/51334/58382).

Comment: so is the solution that Srednicki constructed not a Lorentz invariant one if we allow arbitrary a(k)?

Comment: It would help if you explicitly showed where you think this violates Lorentz covariance/invariance, because I don't see it - $a(k)$ goes to $a(\Lambda^{-1} k)$ under a Lorentz transformation, but Lorentz invariance of the measure means that you can just transform the integration region back to still only have $a(k)$ in there.

Comment: Actually, I find transforming integration region back still problematic.. Say I have $\phi(x) \to \phi(\Lambda^{-1} x) = \int d\tilde{k}[ a(\Lambda^{-1}\mathbf{ k})e^{ikx} + a^*(\Lambda^{-1} \mathbf{k})e^{-ikx}] = \int d\tilde{k}[ a(\mathbf{k})e^{i(\Lambda k)x} + a^*(\mathbf{ k})e^{-i(\Lambda k)x}] =? \phi(x)$.

Comment: @KyleLee: The transformation of a scalar field is $\phi'(x)=\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$. That said, I don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I'm stumped. How does one show that $\phi'(x)=\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ is satisfied by the standard mode expansion in the OP?

Comment: @KyleLee: I see the following in Weinberg: $$U(\Lambda)\phi(x)U^{-1}(\Lambda)=\int d\tilde k[a(\Lambda k)e^{ik(\Lambda x)}+\text{h.c.}]=\int d\tilde k[a(\Lambda (\Lambda^{-1}k))e^{i(\Lambda^{-1}k)(\Lambda x)}+\text{h.c.}]$$
$$=\int d\tilde k[a(k)e^{ikx}+\text{h.c.}]=\phi(x)$$

Comment: @0celo7: Not sure how first equality follows. If we have $\phi(\Lambda^{-1} x)$, does $\Lambda^{-1}$ only transform $x$, or $k$ at the same time?

Comment: I think that's a poor notation. It doesn't work when we consider fields as operators, because the modes (a) don't depend on x but are transformed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spirit of the original post, let $k,x$ be 4-vectors and $\mathbf{k}$, $\mathbf{x}$ the spatial components. Then a quantity of the form
$$\phi(x) \propto \int dk[ a(k)e^{ikx} + a^*(k)e^{-ikx}]$$
is manifestly Lorentz invariant because it does not explicit contain any free Lorentz indices. What Srednicki does is that he performs the $k^0$ integration, resulting in
$$\phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{f(\mathbf{k})}[ a(\mathbf{k})e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} + a^*(\mathbf{k})e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}],$$
which only includes spatial components. This expression is Lorentz invariant because it is just a different form of the previous one, but it does **not manifestly look Lorentz invariant** which I assume what causes the confusion. For an explicit form of the function $f$ which will of course be related to the energy as it is the integral over $k^0$, see for example Peskin and Schroeder eqn (2.47).

---

EDIT: Some more justification:

The Klein-Gordon eqn is
$$\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\phi -m^2\phi=0.$$
To solve it, we Fourier transform to momentum space and we get:
$$(p^\mu p_\mu -m^2)\tilde\phi=0.$$
The general solution of this eqn is
$$\tilde\phi(p)=a(p)\delta(p^\mu p_\mu -m^2),$$
which means that the general solution for the Klein-Gordon is:
$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int d^4pe^{ipx}\tilde\phi(p)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^4}\int d^4pe^{ipx}a(p)\delta(p^\mu p_\mu -m^2)$$
which is manifestly Lorentz invariant. You can then perform the $p^0$ integration as claimed above. I have ignored the complex conjugate term everywhere but should be trivial to restore...

Comment: What about $k^0$ in the argument of exponents ? Why are they still around ?

Comment: @KyleLee: They get put on the mass shell: $k^0=\sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2+m^2}$.

Comment: That's true. Nice !

Comment: Well, one thing that im still confused about is I feel like f(k) should then be appropriately set to make the whole thing Lorentz invariant, not just the measure. I don't see how the coefficients don't play any role in determining f(k) if I integrate the first integral.

Comment: @KyleLee: What worries me more is the first equation. What does $a(k)$ mean? Does that imply it has $k^0$ dependence? I can't recall seeing this expansion before. It's normally the $d\mathbf{k}$ one.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: I thought you were missing that $\delta(p^2-m^2)$ factor.

Comment: @Heterotic: Again, shouldn't integration over $p^0$ give $f(p)$ that dependens on $a(p)$?

Comment: @KyleLee: At school, so I took a pic: http://gyazo.com/ed1844d7413ff428cb54b52b7ebac104. The delta function simply puts $p^0$ on the mass shell, no $p^0$ integral over $a$.

Comment: @KyleLee: Some authors scale $a$ so that one over the square root of the energy appears, rather than one over the energy. Slightly better resolution: http://imgur.com/Z07DtEY

Comment: @0celo7: Very very nice!

Comment: I couldn't reach a conclusion but OP did. Here is what I could  think: $kx$ term is Lorentz invariant, so is measure and field is a scalar, thus $a(k)$ must a Lorentz scalar (since $kx$ is invariant, $k$ transforms covariantly, thus we can talk about how $a$ transforms). Then $a(k)$ is not arbitrary but Lorentz scalar.

Comment: On page 39 of Srednicki ,[link](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf), accepted answer's first equation is written. On page 40, at eq 3.21, author represents $a(k)$ in terms of solution $\phi$. From here how arbitrary $a(k)$ could be is implicitly mentioned. I think if $a(k)$ is truly arbitrary, every arbitrary function ($a(k)$)can be written as some function of solutions of KG equation (by eq 3.21) but this sounds too much strong.