# "Geometric" symmetries

Tags: symmetry

A **symmetry** of a dynamical system is a diffeomorphism of the configuration space which sends solutions of the equations of motion to solutions of the equations of motion. That is, $A$ is a symmetry if 
$$x(t)~\text{is a physical evolution of the system}~~~\to~~~A (x(t))~\text{is a physical evolution of the system}.$$
I am being pedantic here, because, often, the word symmetry is also used to describe an operator $A$ which relates the dynamics of two *different* dynamical systems, sharing the same configuration space:
$$x(t)~\text{is a physical evolution of system 1}~~~\to~~~A (x(t))~\text{is a physical evolution of system 2}.$$
I will call the symmetries mentioned first "symmetries of the first kind", and the latter "symmetries of the second kind". I will now give examples:

- For a particle in an n-dimensional potential, all coordinate transformations in  $GL(n)$ induce symmetries of the first kind on the phase space.
- For electromagnetism, "local $U(1)$-symmetry" is a symmetry of the second kind, and it refers to conjugation by a unitary operator (a gauge transformation). Gauge-equivalences refer to dynamics being related by a gauge transformation.

Now that I've clearly defined these two, I now claim that symmetries of the second kind are vacuous. Therefore, statements of the type 
$$\textit{"EM has a local $U(1)$-symmetry"}$$
are thus vacuous. The problem is, they're just referring to changing coordinates on a geometric object. For example, I could extend the notion of a gauge transformation by allowing it to translate the fibres of the respective bundles, or, even worse, let it be discontinuous. Why not call a gauge-transformation, followed by a translation and dilation, a "fundamental symmetry of electromagnetism"? Why not call a hideous symplectomorphism of a phase space a "symmetry", because it happens to be some arbitrary distortion of the dynamics?

Comment: Gauge symmetries are indeed in a certain sense unphysical, cf. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13870/50583). But you have to note that GR is not a gauge theory - things related by diffeomorphisms (or "local $\mathrm{GL}(4)$ transforms") are *not physically identified*, there are no gauge equivalence classes in GR, since the diffeomorphism acts upon spacetime itself. In gauge theories, the diffeomorphism of a gauge transformation *leaves spacetime untouched* and acts only on the fibers of the gauge principal bundle.

Comment: Also, your type of symmetry is not exactly what physicists would define as a symmetry, cf. [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/51334/50583). You might want to revise your question, I'm currently a bit unsure *what exactly* the question is.

Comment: I guess your first comment answered my question. I was a bit too brash in my tone - I should have communicated more uncertainty (I was like, this can't be right, right?)