# Does Einstein field equation imply there is always conformal symmetry in 2 dimension?

Tags: general-relativity, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If we contract both sides of the Einstein field equation $$R_{\mu \nu }-{\frac {1}{2}}Rg_{\mu \nu }=-{8\pi G}T_{\mu \nu },$$ we will get $$\frac{2-n}{2}R=-8\pi G T_\mu^\mu,$$ where $n$ is the dimension of spacetime. Therefore in 2 dimensional spacetime we always have $T_\mu^\mu=0$, which implies any 2d field theory has conformal symmetry, at least classically. But this statement sounds unreasonable. What's wrong here?

Comment: This may be helpful: Carlip, Lectures in (2+1)-Dimensional Gravity, http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9503024 *which implies any 2d field theory has conformal symmetry, at least classically* Do you mean any 2-dimensional field theory, or just any 2-dimensional spacetime?

Comment: It is true yes, unless you have a cosmological term

Comment: @BenCrowell Thanks, but is that paper for 3d rather than 2d? I mean field theory. Of course, the spacetime needs to have conformal symmetry in the first place so that we can say a field has such symmetry.

Comment: @Slereah I assume there is no cosmological term. I think I can add some terms in the Lagrangian with dimensional coupling to break the conformal symmetry. So why is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analogy: consider an infinitesimal symmetry transformation. Noether's theorem states that the current is conserved if the action doesn't change. But according to the least action principle the infinitesimal variation of the action should always be zero in classical theory! Conclusion: any current is conserved.

This is obviously wrong. But why?

**Spoiler alert: if you like puzzles, you might want to try to figure this out on your own. Below is the answer, don't read it unless you want to :)**

The answer to this is, of course, that the current is conserved if the symmetry doesn't change the action *off-shell*. That is, on any classical configuration, not necessarily satisfying the equations of motion.

A moment of reflection would convince you that the same thing happens here. A field is only conformal-invariant is $T_{\mu}^{\mu}$ vanishes off-shell. That is, without the implication of equations of motion. Einstein's equations have nothing to do with this.

Try checking that stress-energy trace vanishes off-shell for a massless scalar in 2d.

P.S. And yes, I believe Slereah's comment is wrong and misleading.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a point I missed before. I would like to paraphrase your ideas as following to check whether I got it correctly: Symmetry is _defined_ to generate a horizontal motion in the action space (i.e. the action doesn't change) _anywhere_, not just at the lowest part (the Euler-Lagrange Equation). Therefore a symmetry of the action must be a symmetry of the Euler-Lagrange Equation, but the converse is not necessarily true, which happened in this question. The catch here is that usually the symmetry generator itself doesn't show up in the Euler-Lagrange Equation.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/do-an-action-and-its-euler-lagrange-equations-have-the-same-symmetries) should be a relevant question.

Comment: Now my question would be why a symmetry is defined to leave the action invariant, rather than, for example, leave the equation of motion invariant?

Comment: @WunderNatur no, the relevant thing is the symmetry of equations of motion. The symmetry of the action guarantees the symmetry of the equations of motion, however, only when it is valid off-shell.

Comment: @WunderNatur my point is — equations of motion are only conformal-invariant when the stress-energy trace vanishes *off-shell*.

Comment: I think the symmetry of an action is by definition valid off-shell. A symmetry of an action is sufficient but not necessary to a symmetry of equations of motion. That is, there can be a symmetry of equations of motion which is not a symmetry of the action. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51327/do-an-action-and-its-euler-lagrange-equations-have-the-same-symmetries) provided lots of examples.

Comment: @WunderNatur I never said that there couldn't be one. Again, I only claim that equations of motion are guaranteed to be conformal-invariant when stress-energy trace vanishes off-shell, that is, is identically equal to zero, without implying eom for either the field itself or gravity. Which was your original mistake.

Comment: Yes, and that's a good point, but which statement in my paraphrase do you think is incorrect or imprecise? Thanks.

Comment: @WunderNatur your paraphrase is correct. At first I got confused by your terminology, sorry.