# A Scalar Function Tranformation -- Question on Notation in 't Hooft Document

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, field-theory, coordinate-systems, invariants

I started reading a document by Gerard 't Hooft which can be found [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/basisqft.pdf).  Right at the start I am puzzled by a simple expression.  It is equation 2.2 showing how a scalar function transforms.  I repeat the equation here:
$$
\phi^\prime(x) = \phi(x^\prime). \tag{2.2} 
$$
This does not look right to me.  I would expect this to read like:
$$
\phi^\prime(x^\prime) = \phi(x).
$$
Am I missing something trivial or is this a typo?

Comment: There are tons of differing conventions for this kind of thing -- everybody sets it up their own way. It gets worse -- for the transformation of the action there are _fifteen_ possible conventions, which I outlined [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365379/what-does-it-mean-for-an-action-to-be-invariant-under-x-to-x-phi-to-phi).

Comment: In my opinion the best thing to do is to try to set it all up yourself, in a way that works for you (i.e. so that your calculations get correct results), then basically ignore whatever anybody else does. You can only learn physics by reinventing it, anyway.

Comment: @knzhou-- thanks for the link and comments.  Yes this is a confusing bag of notation.  I think I need to study also active versus passive transformations.  Actually never heard of that before.

Comment: OK, after a brief look at active and passive transformations I guess I do know what these are -- just didn't know they had a name.

Comment: Yeah. God knows if that's what t'Hooft had in mind. He could also have just swapped the usual meanings of $x$ and $x'$. There are no universal conventions on this. A more 'casual' document like the one you linked just wouldn't be careful to be consistent on this either.

Comment: As long as you can see what's going on and do calculations correctly, you're fine!