# Sign in Peierls substitution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, second-quantization, tight-binding

A method often used to couple a lattice tight binding model to a magnetic field is the Peierls substitution, whereby one changes all hopping elements (schematically) as $t_{ij}\mapsto t_{ij}\exp(\mathrm{i}Q\int A\,\mathrm{d}l)$. I have looked in a number of places, and there seems to be no consistent agreement about whether the sign in the exponent is to be positive or negative. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peierls_substitution) gives three arguments for the method; they seem equally plausible to me, yet give opposite signs. I have reproduced (and slightly altered) two of these arguments below ($\hbar=1$). Which conclusion is correct and why?

> **Method 1:**
>
> The hopping matrix element $t_{ij}$ is proportional to the amplitude
> $\langle \mathbf{r}_i, t_i|\mathbf{r}_j, t_j\rangle$, which can be
> calculated for a free particle as  $$ \langle \mathbf{r}_i, t_i|\mathbf{r}_j, t_j\rangle
> =\int_{\mathbf{r}(t_i)}^{\mathbf{r}(t_j)}\mathcal{D}\mathbf{r}(t)\,\exp\left(\mathrm{i}\mathcal{S}_0\right),
>  $$ where $\mathcal{S}_0=\int L_0\,\mathrm{d}t$  is the action. If the
> particle has charge $Q$ then the effect of introducing a magnetic
> field is to change $L_0\mapsto L_0+Q \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A}$, so
> the action changes as  \begin{align}
>  \mathcal{S}_0=\int_{t_i}^{t_j}L_0\,\mathrm{d}t\mapsto&
>  \int_{t_i}^{t_j}L_0+Q\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
> &=\int_{t_i}^{t_j}L_0\,\mathrm{d}t
>  +Q\int_{t_i}^{t_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm{d}
>  t}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
> &=
>  \mathcal{S}_0+Q\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}
>  \end{align} and the amplitude changes to \begin{align} \langle \mathbf{r}_i,
>  t_i|\mathbf{r}_j, t_j\rangle\mapsto
>  &\int_{\mathbf{r}(t_i)}^{\mathbf{r}(t_j)}\mathcal{D}\mathbf{r}(t)\,\exp\left(\mathrm{i}\mathcal{S}_0+\mathrm{i}Q\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right)\\
>  &\approx
>  \exp\left(\mathrm{i}Q\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right)\int_{\mathbf{r}(t_i)}^{\mathbf{r}(t_j)}\mathcal{D}\mathbf{r}(t)\,\exp\left(\mathrm{i}\mathcal{S}_0\right)\\
>  &=\exp\left(\mathrm{i}Q\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right)\langle
>  \mathbf{r}_i, t_i|\mathbf{r}_j, t_j\rangle \end{align} where in the
> second line we have made the (saddle point) approximation that
> $\mathbf{A}$ varies little over paths which contribute the most to the
> amplitude. Thus, the hopping element must change as $$ t_{ij}\propto
>  \langle \mathbf{r}_i, t_i|\mathbf{r}_j, t_j\rangle\mapsto
>  \exp\left(\mathrm{i}Q\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right)\langle
>  \mathbf{r}_i, t_i|\mathbf{r}_j, t_j\rangle\propto
>  \exp\left(+\mathrm{i}Q\int_{\mathbf{r}_i}^{\mathbf{r}_j}\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right)
>  t_{ij} $$

On the other hand, we can make an argument about the required substitution by considering a lattice model

> **Method 2**:
>
> Consider the tight binding Hamiltonian $$ H_0 =
>  -\sum_{ij} t_{ij} c_{i}^{\dagger} c_j \sim -\sum_{ij}t_{ij}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_i}\rangle\langle\phi_{\mathbf{R}_j}| $$ where $t_{ij} = t^*_{ji}$. We can rewrite the state $|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_i}\rangle$
> using the translation operator as $$ |\phi_{\mathbf{R}_i}\rangle =
>  \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot\mathbf{p}}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_j}\rangle
>  $$ Under minimal coupling, we change $\mathbf{p}\mapsto
>  \mathbf{p}-Q\mathbf{A}$, which means that  \begin{align}
>  \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot\mathbf{p}}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_j}\rangle\mapsto &\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot(\mathbf{p}-Q\mathbf{A})}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_j}\rangle\\
> &\approx\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot Q\mathbf{A}}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot\mathbf{p}}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_j}\rangle
>  \\
> &= \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot Q\mathbf{A}}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_i}\rangle \end{align} where we have neglected higher order terms. The effect of this on the
> Hamiltonian is $$ H_0\mapsto- \sum_{ij}t_{ij}
>  \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot
>  Q\mathbf{A}}|\phi_{\mathbf{R}_i}\rangle\langle\phi_{\mathbf{R}_j}|  $$ which is
> equivalent to  $$
>  t_{ij}\mapsto\exp\left(\mathrm{i}(\mathbf{R}_i-\mathbf{R}_j)\cdot
>  Q\mathbf{A}\right) t_{ij}\approx \exp\left(-\mathrm{i}Q
>  \int_{\mathbf{R}_i}^{\mathbf{R}_j}
>  \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\right) t_{ij} $$

Comment: The "right" sign depends on your convention for the sign of $Q$. Unfortunately, sources are split about 50/50 on this because the charge of the electron is inconveniently negative. So sometimes, $Q$ stands for the charge of the electron (negative), and other times $Q$ stands for the absolute value of the charge of the electron (positive). As long as you're consistent, there's no problem.

Comment: @knzhou Correct me if I'm wrong, but a Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x})^2+Q \dot{x}A$ corresponds to a Hamiltonian $H=(p-QA)^2/(2m)$. Hence, the exponent of the translation operator should be $\propto (p-QA)$, with the relative sign between $A,p$ being the same as in the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan Whoops, I read this too quickly! I think the first argument shows the additional phase you pick up given a vector potential, while the second argument shows how to define transition elements to _get rid_ of that additional phase. Those are opposites, so we expect them to differ by a sign. The real problem is that the "blah $\to$ blah" notation in physics is horribly [ambiguous](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609336/does-the-structure-constant-of-yang-mills-field-change-sign-under-time-reversal/610465#610465).

Comment: @knzhou maybe I'm missing something here, but in the 2nd argument, he just uses minimal substitution. If I understand correctly, what you say is that in the 2nd argument, he uses a gauge transformation to gauge away the additional phase, but why is this the case? I don't see it.