# If the equation of motion is not invariant under time reversal, is the Lagrangian not either?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

Suppose the Euler-Lagrange equation of a system $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\Bigg)$$  is known to be *not* invariant under the discrete transformation $t\to -t$. It's given. Also assume that nothing is known about the functional form of the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q},t)$.

*Is it possible to infer from that information whether the Lagrangian (or action) will be invariant under $t\to -t$ or not?*

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question asks if T-asymmetry of the equations of motion implies T-asymmetry of the Lagrangian. That's equivalent to asking if T-symmetry of the Lagrangian implies T-symmetry of the equations of motion.

The answer is yes, by the principle of least action. Specifically, T-symmetry of the Lagrangian implies the paths $q(t)$ and $q(-t)$ have the same action. Then $q(t)$ is a stationary point of the action if and only if $q(-t)$ is, so if $q(t)$ solves the equation of motion, so does $q(-t)$.

To clarify questions in the comments, very explicitly, the facts are

- symmetries of the action imply symmetries of the EOM
- asymmetries of the EOM imply asymmetries of the action
- symmetries of the EOM don't imply symmetries of the action
- asymmetries of the action don't imply asymmetries of the EOM

Comment: My question is whether the *non*-invariance of the EOM under $t\to -t$ implies *non*-invariance of the Lagrangian? @knzhou

Comment: @SRS I am using the contrapositive: "not A implies not B" is logically equivalent to "B implies A".

Comment: To understand your point let me ask you the following. Would also say that if an EOM is invariant under $t\to t+t_0$ (time-translation), the Lagrangian will also be invariant under $t\to t+t_0$? @knzhou

Comment: @SRS No, not at all. For a very simple example, let $L = \dot{q}^2 + t$. The equation of motion is time translation invariant, as it is simply $\dot{q} = 0$.

Comment: So your point is that only under time-reversal both the EOM and the action have the same behaviour. Am I getting it correct? @knzhou

Comment: @SRS The point is that symmetries of the action give symmetries of the EOM, which is logically equivalent to saying that asymmetries of the EOM imply asymmetries of the action. However, the converse/inverse of these statements is not true.

Comment: Regarding your example of adding  $t$ to the Lagrangian, what if we disregard total derivatives in the Lagrangian?

Comment: @innisfree How about $L = t \dot{q}^2$? The equation of motion is $\ddot{q} + \dot{q} = 0$.