# Are equations of motion invariant under gauge transformations?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, gauge-theory, variational-principle, gauge-invariance

We know that all actions are invariant under their gauge transformations. Are the equations of motion also invariant under the gauge transformations?

If yes, can you show a mathematical proof (instead of just saying in words)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since the action is the same the path of least action is also the same