# Is the invariance of the Lagrangian under some transformation equivalent to the covariance of the motion equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, covariance

Take the Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}m{{\left( \frac{{\rm{d}}}{{\rm{d}}t}x \right)}^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}k{{x}^{2}}$, for example.

The equation of motion of this system should be given by $m\frac{{{{\rm{d}}}^{2}}}{{\rm{d}}{{t}^{2}}}x+kx=0$.

Now considering the transform $x\to x+\varepsilon$.

The Lagrangian is not invariant under this transform so there is no reservation of momentum, but I'm not so sure whether the equation of motion is "covariant" under this transform.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/2451 and links therein.